# Trigger function on chosen-select multiple

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-chosen

I need to increase or decrease the cost on selecting multiple options from a jquery multiple chosen select. The cost will increase on selecting options and will decrease by removing the option.

```
<select multiple="" class="chosen-select" id="form-field-select-4" data-placeholder="Choose a Department...">
    <option value="Management">Senior Management</option>
    <option value="Legal">Legal</option>
    <option value="Operations">Operations</option>
    <option value="Administration">Administration</option>
    <option value="R&D">R&D</option>
</select>
```

The cost will increase if end user chooses more departments and will decrease by removing the chosen department.

How can I trigger a function on change of this multiple select and how do I get if end user has added a new option or removed a chosen one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `option:selected` to get the selected options and use them to calculate the amount on change of selection of select. The will automatically remove the deselected `options` being returned by collection and you do not have to remember what is deselected and selected.

```
$("#form-field-select-4 option:selected")
```

Comment: how do I get the selected values in an array from the object which above js code returns? As of now I am looping the object and push each value to make a new selected options array

Comment: The selector will return you collection of option object and you use them as array using eq(index) you can get elements. You can also use map to make iterate and array array.

Comment: var departmentVal = $(".departmentOption option:selected");
$.map( departmentVal, function( val, i ) {
 console.clear();
 console.log(val, i);
});

console Output:  
<option value="Operations"> 1

how do I get the Operations only?

Comment: $.map( departmentVal, function( val, i ) { console.clear(); console.log(val.value); }); to get array you would need $.map( departmentVal, var arr = function( val, i ) { console.clear(); return val.value });